# How can I sync two audio sources running at different speeds

Tags: vegas-pro

I know Vegas is more of a video editor, but I like the visuality and ease of syncing audio.  I've done this easily with 2 digital sources, it's a snap.

The problem lies when you try to sync old analog sources that were recorded on different equipment and different battery strengths.

I've got two sources.  On one source, the required clip runs exactly 2,481 seconds long (from 4:16:24 to 45:37:00 on my timeline).  The source I want to mix it with runs exactly 2,422 seconds long (from 4:16:24 to 44:38:00 on my timeline).  I calculated this by syncing exactly the start point and lining the 2 tracks up, and then determining the exact same end point on both tracks.

How can I sync these so they both run the same length of time, and match up along the way?

I'm using Sony Vegas Pro 13.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I sorta figured it out so I'll put it as an answer, although I hope someone comes up with a better suggestion.

I had to eventually cut one track into (approximately) 5 minute segments.  I placed my cursor at the end of each segment, held the shift key and did a click-and-drag with my mouse to perform a "time shift" until the tracks aligned.  Then, I moved the next clip up against the first and repeated the process.  I found if I did this with the entire track, it still went out of sync, so by chopping the track into (approximately) 5 minute intervals it kept it closer to sync.  That might be due to the speed of the source tape varying as the batteries got weaker.  I tried to cut the track near a large volume peak or valley to make it visually easier to align the tracks.

All in all, it was still much easier than trying to do this with something like Audacity or Sound Forge.